# SQL - Update status using Trigger after Insert, Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a trigger.

Basically I have a table `Reserves`, that as the state of the reserve. And each reserve can have a x number of `Reserveitems`.

The `ReserveItems` have an `OfferID` as a fk to connect that table to a `OfferItems` table that as the price of each possible offer.

Table **Item_RESERVE**

```
[ID_RESERVE]
[ID_ITEMRESERVE]
[ID_OFFER]
[ID_ITEMOFFER]
```

Table **RESERVE**

```
[ID_RESERVE]
[STATE_RESERVE]
[TOTAL]
```

Table **Item_OFFERS**

```
[ID_OFFER]
[ID_ITEMOFFER]
[PRICE]
```

Basically, I have to ensure that every time the price in `Item_OFFER` is equal to 0, the `State_Reserve` changes to 'Paid'.

So I've written this trigger (posted below), where I'm trying to ensure that when there are `ReserveItems` with the same `ID_RESERVE` and `ID_ITEMSOFFER` with price = 0, the trigger fires. But I'm failing to ensure that in the reserves that have more than 2 ReservedItems linked all the `ID_RESERVE` are the same.

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_8  
ON Items_reserva
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS  
   UPDATE RESERVAS
   SET ESTADO_DA_RESERVA = 'Paga', total = 0.00
   WHERE reservas.id_reserva IN (SELECT r.ID_RESERVA
                                 FROM RESERVAS r, ITEMS_RESERVA ir, ITEMS_RESERVA ir1, ITEMS_OFERTA io
                                 WHERE r.ID_RESERVA = ir.ID_RESERVA 
                                   AND ir.Id_Reserva = ir1.ID_RESERVA 
                                   AND io.ID_ITEMOFERTA = ir.ID_ITEMOFERTA 
                                   AND io.PRECO = 0)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also: in your trigger, you need to look at the `Inserted` (and possibly `Deleted`) pseudo tables - those contain the rows that are being inserted (or updated). Right now, you're always updating across the whole tables..... even if just a single row is inserted. This is highly inefficient.....